# Do you know a good html mailing list management software with admin levels?

Tags: email, tracking, software, mailing-list, management

I'm basically looking for a program/app/script (can be commercial) which I can ideally install on a windows server (we can run asp, asp.net php mssql)

we have different groups of people who send newsletters to web members, I want to bring it all into one app which I can monitor and control. Ideally it would be able to create html newsletters, (with some templates) track emails and click throughs. Manage email lists subscribe/unsubscribes. And importantly have different levels of admin, so a newsletter creator could log in and create and send off an email, it goes into a queue where a communications editor can have an overview of all newsletters and approve the sending of the emails or edit them before they are sent off.

before I start coding something up myself I thought I'd ask if anyone has any advice!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [phplist](http://www.phplist.com/), it's free or [Interspire Email Marketer](http://www.interspire.com/emailmarketer/) is a paid version ~$400.

Comment: I would recommend phplist too, I've no experience of it in a Windows environment but use it on my Linux based server, seem to do everything that is required

Answer (score 0):

I also use and recommend phplist.